# How to set the KeyIdentifier in the SecurityTokenReference to the Assertion ID with WSS4j

Tags: soap, cxf, saml-2.0, wss4j

I'm a bit of a Noob with WSS4J so I'm hoping I'm missing something simple. I'm trying to create a Security header for an outbound SOAP message using WSS4j and CXF. As per the requirements the Assertion and the Timestamp have to be signed. The Assertion is done in a SAMLCallback and the Timestamp with the properties for the WSS4JOutInterceptor. All of that is straight forward. The hitch is instead of embedding the KeyInfo information for the Timestamp signature in the Signature, I need to reference the Assertion, which has the KeyInfo for it's Signature within it. So the Signature for the Timestamp's KeyInfo should look like this:

```
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0">
                    <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLID">3a4edd62-458e-4c3f-adc0-a9b505cb6284</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
```

Note how the KeyIdentifier points to and ID which is the ID of the Assertion. I've tried all the different WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID options for the WSS4JOutInterceptor but all of them populate the KeyInfo element with the information from the certificate. I'm hoping there is some straightforward solution within the WSS4J framework for this. Otherwise I'm looking at writing an interceptor to hack up the SOAP header.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, here's a test I pushed to CXF to show how it can be done:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/commit/5504cad08be5f2eb8396410618da68cb732b80e0

Comment: That was it. I thought I had tried every possible option of the properties on the interceptor and callback I could think of, but obviously missed one. The trick was setting the setSignAssertion to true on the callback AND setting the the SAML_TOKEN_SIGNED on the interceptor. Thanks much.